# how to split a string multiple times dynamically and pivot into groups in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table like below:

```
ref_id

21121212122233333333
21222233333333333333
22112212333333333333
22213333333333333333
```

Result should look like this

```
ref_id            `Group_1  ` `Group_2`Group_3`Group_4`Group_5`

21121212122233333333    2      112      12      12      1222
21222233333333333333    2      12222            
22112212333333333333    22     1122     12      
12213333333333333333    122    1
```

The query would take the part of the string prior to the number 1 (eg. 2 or 22) and take the part of the string from 1 to the next part of the string prior to 1 (eg 12222) but not including 3. I note that there may be 'n' number of groups.

Not sure how to do this ... any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what you have tried so far ??

Comment: This is a task more suited to a programming language then to Sql.

Comment: The two tables don't match. Is that first character on the fourth line of the second table supposed to be a '2'?

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @ref TABLE (RowID INT IDENTITY, ref_id NVARCHAR (20))
DECLARE @refunpivot TABLE (RowID INT, ColumnID INT, RefString NVARCHAR(20))
DECLARE @refpivot TABLE  (RowID INT IDENTITY
                         ,ref_id    NVARCHAR (20)
                         ,Group_01  NVARCHAR (20)
                         ,Group_02  NVARCHAR (20)
                         ,Group_03  NVARCHAR (20)
                         ,Group_04  NVARCHAR (20)
                         ,Group_05  NVARCHAR (20)
                         ,Group_06  NVARCHAR (20)
                         ,Group_07  NVARCHAR (20)
                         ,Group_08  NVARCHAR (20)
                         ,Group_09  NVARCHAR (20)
                         ,Group_10  NVARCHAR (20)
                         )

INSERT INTO @ref VALUES
        ('21121212122233333333'),
        ('21222233333333333333'),
        ('22112212333333333333'),
        ('22213333333333333333')


DECLARE @refstring NVARCHAR (20)
DECLARE @Counter1 INT = 0
DECLARE @Counter2 INT = 0
DECLARE @Marker INT

WHILE @Counter1 < (SELECT MAX(RowID) FROM @ref) BEGIN
    SET @Counter1 += 1
    SET @refstring = (SELECT ref_id FROM @ref WHERE RowID = @Counter1)
    SET @refstring = LEFT(@refstring,CHARINDEX('3',@refstring)-1)
    SET @Counter2 = 0
    WHILE CHARINDEX('1',@refstring) > 0 BEGIN
        SET @Counter2 += 1
        SET @Marker = CHARINDEX('1',RIGHT(@refstring,LEN(@refstring)-1))
        INSERT INTO @refunpivot SELECT @Counter1, @Counter2, LEFT(@refstring,@Marker)
        SET @refstring = RIGHT(@refstring,LEN(@refstring)-@Marker)
        IF CHARINDEX('1',RIGHT(@refstring,LEN(@refstring)-1)) = 0
            BEGIN
                SET @Counter2 += 1
                INSERT INTO @refunpivot SELECT @Counter1, @Counter2, @refstring
                SET @refstring = ''
            END

        END     

    END

SET @Counter1 = 0

    WHILE @Counter1 < (SELECT MAX(RowID) FROM @refunpivot) BEGIN
        SET @Counter1 += 1
        INSERT INTO @refpivot (ref_id) 
            SELECT ref_id FROM @ref WHERE RowID = @Counter1
        UPDATE @refpivot
            SET Group_01 = COALESCE((SELECT RefString FROM @refunpivot WHERE RowID = @Counter1 AND ColumnID = 1),'')
                WHERE RowID = @Counter1
        UPDATE @refpivot
            SET Group_02 = COALESCE((SELECT RefString FROM @refunpivot WHERE RowID = @Counter1 AND ColumnID = 2),'')
                WHERE RowID = @Counter1
        UPDATE @refpivot
            SET Group_03 = COALESCE((SELECT RefString FROM @refunpivot WHERE RowID = @Counter1 AND ColumnID = 3),'')
                WHERE RowID = @Counter1
        UPDATE @refpivot
            SET Group_04 = COALESCE((SELECT RefString FROM @refunpivot WHERE RowID = @Counter1 AND ColumnID = 4),'')
                WHERE RowID = @Counter1
        UPDATE @refpivot
            SET Group_05 = COALESCE((SELECT RefString FROM @refunpivot WHERE RowID = @Counter1 AND ColumnID = 5),'')
                WHERE RowID = @Counter1
        UPDATE @refpivot
            SET Group_06 = COALESCE((SELECT RefString FROM @refunpivot WHERE RowID = @Counter1 AND ColumnID = 6),'')
                WHERE RowID = @Counter1
        UPDATE @refpivot
            SET Group_07 = COALESCE((SELECT RefString FROM @refunpivot WHERE RowID = @Counter1 AND ColumnID = 7),'')
                WHERE RowID = @Counter1
        UPDATE @refpivot
            SET Group_08 = COALESCE((SELECT RefString FROM @refunpivot WHERE RowID = @Counter1 AND ColumnID = 8),'')
                WHERE RowID = @Counter1
        UPDATE @refpivot
            SET Group_09 = COALESCE((SELECT RefString FROM @refunpivot WHERE RowID = @Counter1 AND ColumnID = 9),'')
                WHERE RowID = @Counter1
        UPDATE @refpivot
            SET Group_10 = COALESCE((SELECT RefString FROM @refunpivot WHERE RowID = @Counter1 AND ColumnID = 10),'')
                WHERE RowID = @Counter1

        END

SELECT * FROM @refpivot
```

I'm no good with pivot tables; this could probably be improved with those. I also thought about dynamic SQL for my update statements, but I couldn't figure that out, either. But this should at least get you started. Also bear in mind that I couldn't reconcile your table values with your instructions exactly, so I've done what made the most sense to me. It should be fairly elementary to make modifications from here.

Here are the results I got:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
declare @t table (ref_id varchar(50)) insert into @t (ref_id) values
('21121212122233333333'),
('21222233333333333333'),
('22112212333333333333'),
('12213333333333333333')
declare @n varchar(max)

SELECT distinct ref_id

, S.a.value('(/t)[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS Group_1 
, S.a.value('(/t)[2]', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS Group_2
, S.a.value('(/t)[3]', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS Group_3
, S.a.value('(/t)[4]', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS Group_4
, S.a.value('(/t)[5]', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS Group_5
FROM
(

select ref_id, cast('<t>'+replace(replace(ref_id,'3',''),'21','2</t><t>1') +'</t>' as xml) as [val]  from @t) d

CROSS APPLY d.[val].nodes('/t') S(a)
```

Comment: hi nazmark can you explain the following xml code you have written select ref_id, cast('<t>'+replace(replace(ref_id,'3',''),'21','2</t><t>1') +'</t>' as xml) as [val]  from @t) d

CROSS APPLY d.[val].nodes('/t') S(a) as my xml knowledge is not to great. Thanks

Comment: read https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/sql-server-xml-questions-you-were-too-shy-to-ask/

Comment: don't forget to click the accept solution..thank you.

Comment: Thanks nazmark ... you were spot on. Took me a bit of time to understand your solution but i think i understand the majority of it. Thanks for your help and expertise.